# House rules for Crokinole?

Tags: house-rules, crokinole

Any recommendations or variants for playing Crokinole? We say that you have to stay seated in your chair with at least one cheek touching to make your shot.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that rule to be incorrect, but interesting. You must hit an enemy disc, but you can hit a friendly disc first to make a combo shot.  It's higher risk because you can lose multiple discs. Check the WCC webpage for official rules.  Also the one cheek rule is standard here in clubs in Ontario as well as not being able to move/shift your chair in any way once play begins.

Answer (score 1):

The rules around chair movement and contact with your chair during play are explained in the [National Crokinole Association (NCA) rules](http://nationalcrokinoleassociation.com/resources/NCA%20Rules%20Feb%209,%202011.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> 7) Shooting

...

> h) Neither the board, nor the chair, of any player may be moved while the game is in progress, excep that a player may move his chair, if necessary, to pick up a disc that has fallen out of reach.
>
> i) When a player is shooting, **at least one portion of his/her posterior must be in contact with the seat of his/her chair**.
>
> j) Each leg of a player's chair must be in contact with the floor. (no leaning of the chair)
>
> k) No part of a player's body except the feet, may touch the floor. No other means of support may be utilized

Comment: While interesting to note that the rule mentioned in the question is actually an official rule as opposed to a house rule, this answer doesn't answer the question; which is asking for variants or house rules that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the [standard rules on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crokinole)

> If there are any enemy discs on the board, a player must make contact, directly or indirectly, with an enemy disc during the shot. If unsuccessful, the shot disc is 'fouled' and removed from the board, along with any of the player's other discs that were moved during the shot.

We always played with this rule : If there are any enemy discs on the board, a player must **make contact with an enemy disc directly and before making contact with any friendly disk**  during the shot (bumpers use is tolerated). If he miss, **only the disk shoot by the player is fooled.**

Comment: [National Crokinole Association (NCA) rules](http://nationalcrokinoleassociation.com/resources/NCA%20Rules%20Feb%209,%202011.pdf) disagree with this:
3) Valid Shot
a) Definition
i) lf any opposing discs are in play, at least one of the shooter's discs must strike an opposing disc either directly, or by bumping one of his/her discs already in play into an opposing disc.
b) lf on any turn, a valid shot is not made, then the shooting disc and all of the other discs that were struck, including any 20's made, shall be removed, considered out-of-play, and shall not score.

Comment: @3N1GM4 The answer is about a house rule suggestion; it is intended to differ from the official rules.